Do we have a layout for the site yet?
On area 51 we still need more questions asked to get our full site. That said does anyone thought of a layout yet? 

While those stats are important and I agree that we should try to shoot for optimal in every category, I have seen other sites graduate with stats in the red/orange. I think StackExchange just wants to see a healthy thriving self-sustaining community which I think we absolutely have.
As for the design/layout, SE employs an excellent web designer and we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

Oh ok I see so we do not need a web designer for our selves...perfect.
